# start a another version of an existing broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `fragment` with a button that starts a `BroadcastReceiver`.  This `BroadcastReciever` creates a notification after a time retrieved from the fragment.  This part works.
However, when I press the button more than once, the existing broadcast receiver is overwritten.  I don't want this as I want multiple notifications to be created.

Any solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - The pending intent used in the alarm manager was not unique so it was overwritten each time I created another alarm.  What I needed to do was create multiple alarms.  This is done by adding a unique id to the 2nd parameter (argument?) of the pending intent.

See this answer for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090378/2442638