# How to set multiple Alarms at different times in Android Programatically?

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms

I tried to create multiple alarms at different times in Android. And I googled for it. But I can't understand how can we create? Can anybody share?

I want to create alaram at 8am, 1pm, 7pm.

So, how can I create like this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alarmManager.setRepeating()` method with different request codes which will avoid overwriting the alarms. if you do not want repeating alarm then try to set interval value to `0`.

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785702/android-set-multiple-alarms) for more info and
If you need the code example then follow this [link](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Alarm Manager. And for different alarms you need to give each alarm an Unique id. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469705/how-to-set-multiple-alarms-using-android-alarm-manager) is the helpful link over the stackoverflow. try this and let me know.And [here](https://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/tag/multiple-alarms/) is the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use void set (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation) in [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).