# How do i set Repeating Alarm for user selected days?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

**Condition :**
User selects a active time period (from  and to) for a day within which the alarm should be active with user specified interval.
User selects a inactive time period (from  and to) for a day within which the alarm should be inactive or silent.
User selects the days on which the alarm should be fired.

eg: a user selects the active period of the alarm to be 9:00 am to 6:00pm with an interval of 20 minutes.
and he don't want the alarm to notify during his break time.say lunch break time is from 1:00 pm to 2:00 pm.He wasnts the alarm to be active only on Tuesday,Thursday and Sunday.
So during Tuesday, Thursday and Sunday ,the alarm should fire at 9:00am and fire with an interval of 20 minutes till 6:00pm. In between the alarm should be silent for 1:00pm to 2:00pm.

The user sets the timings in the main activity and the alarm for those timings is set in another activity where the alarm can be set and canceled.

**Variables:**

Active from time(in millisec) : int AFrom

Active to time (in millisec) : int ATo

Break from time (in millisec) : int BFrom

Break to time (in millisec) : int Bto

Alarm firing Interval (in millisec)  : int interval

To select no: of days using a Android Alert Dialog with Multiple checkboxes:

```
String days[] = {"MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY","SUNDAY"} ;
Boolean checkedDays[] = {false,true,false,true,false,true,false};
final ArrayList DaysSelected = new ArrayList();
```

(this is just for information. Actual working Dialog box is created already. Just want to use the selected day's index for checking with the calendar day)

days[] is referenced with checkedDays[] to identify the selected days in setMultiChoiceItems().

**Inside setMultiChioceItems():**

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(days, checkedDays,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {


                    @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId,
                                        boolean isSelected) {
                        if (isSelected) {

                            DaysSelected .add(selectedItemId);
                        } else if (DaysSelected .contains(selectedItemId)) {

                         DaysSelected .remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedItemId));
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Alarm has to be set for the days whose checkedDays[] values are true

**Note :All the variables all set static to use across all activities.**

with the above variables how do I fire the below alarm for my above required condition?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Notifier.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivitythis.getApplicationContext(),
                 12345, intent, FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
    AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AT_from , interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: you will need different pending intents for different days, check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469705/how-to-set-multiple-alarms-using-android-alarm-manager)

Comment: Okay. How do i silence the alarm in between the active period?