# Schedule local notification Xamarin Forms

Tags: notifications, xamarin.forms, alarmmanager

I have a question about local notification in Xamarin.
I need to be able schedule more than one local notification in different hours.

What I mean ...

day 1
notification 1 - h 10 am - remember appointment 1
notification 2 - h 02 pm - remember appointment 2
notification 3 - h 08 pm - remember appointment 3

day 2
notification 1 - h 08 am - remember appointment 1
notification 2 - h 11 am - remember appointment 2
notification 3 - h 03 pm - remember appointment 3

I read [this article](http://nnish.com/2014/12/16/scheduled-notifications-in-android-using-alarm-manager/) but the implementation with SetInexactRepeating doesn't work in my case because the manager rememeber only one notification (example appointment 1) and not anything else.

Does Xamarin allow to create this scenario? And if yes, can anyone help me?

Comment: Check out this plugin: https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have multiple alarms in Android, each one needs a unique identifier. In the article you linked to, zero is used each time. This could be your problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090378/15904) for how to pass a unique identifier to the getBroadcast call (note passing _id instead of 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(load.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```