# Xamarin.forms how to add Local Reminder

Tags: xamarin.forms, localnotification, reminders

I make a Xamarin.forms app and try to make a reminder. I follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications).

I've created everything and tested and work perfectly fine. Now my scenario is every user can add one or more reminders. Reminder can be called from every hour to every day depending on how the user configure the reminder.

How to organize this? My main question is how to save that list of reminders in the device and depending on time the OS should call it?

Comment: You could make a database and save all the reminders. When you want to show the reminders, you could get the list from database. Check the local database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT my idea is this. The user enter one or more reminders with DateTime. For example he set reminder in 4 hours. App can be open or closed but notification must remind him. Did i need to save this in the OS ?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT i need to schedule the notifications

Comment: You could use `PendingIntent.GetBroadcast` repeat. Please check the links below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394282/schedule-local-notification-xamarin-forms      https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71168/sending-local-notifications-after-some-time-in-xamarin-android

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thank u i will see

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT this is only for android . Do u have for ios?

Comment: For iOS, you can add the properties repeatInterval or repeatCalendar. Check the link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT and for Android i need BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: There are many ways. You could check the sample code in the link i provided.